# Can I save my free upgrade to Lion?

Tags: macos, backup, upgrade

I've bought a MacBook Pro 8,1 one month ago. Snow Leopard was pre-installed on it. Yesterday, I did the free upgrade, provided by Apple. I received a code for the App Store. I filled it in, and I got immediately the OS X Lion upgrade tool (after downloading). But is there a way to put the new OS X, on a DVD as backup?

Please, keep in mind that everything is legal.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to avoid a download again or to avoid needing an internet connection entirely?

Comment: @bmike: If it is possible to redownload it from the App Store, without having to buy it, there is no problem. But I want to be sure that I have a backup of Lion. It doesn't matter where. On the Apple Servers or on a DVD or whatever.

Comment: You can re-download Lion again and again since that code has granted license to your Apple ID as if you paid for it with money. The people whose macs shipped with Lion didn't get a code and will need the Recovery HD to avoid paying again. Apple paid for your upgrade so you only need to sign in with the same account.

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is ambiguous whether you want to

a) Be able to reinstall Lion in future, if, say your HD crashed.

or

b) Save your Lion install to prevent having to download it again.

or

c) Create a bootable install disk.

If a):

The Apple Recovery Disk Assistant will create a rescue disk for you on a USB drive. Follow this link:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433

When you use it, the latest version of Lion will be downloaded from their servers. NB You do **not** need a copy of your Snow Leopard install disk to use this.

If b)

You need to save the "Install Mac OS X Lion" app which is downloaded from the app store when you install Lion. The other answer here by bmike will tell you how to do that.

if c) see:

http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive

Regarding legality: a) and b) are permitted by Apple, c) is probably not.

Comment: However, to make your own bootable install disk (with no downloading from Apple) see these instructions,
http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive
however, this method probably violates some terms of the Lion license. If you want to stay 100% legal, stick with the Recovery Disk Assistant.

Comment: How does having a recovery disk allow the saving of the download for later? It just boots the mac and provides a very limited toolset.

Comment: A limited toolset which includes reinstalling Lion - which is what he wanted to acheive!

Comment: I have reworded my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - since your mac has bootable Snow Leopard media - you can simply store that Install Mac OS X Lion on a USB drive / hard drive or burn it to a DVD. You could install Snow Leopard on your mac without an internet connection, make an account and copy the installer to the hard drive.

I'm fairly certain that installer does not check for an internet connection or have any sort of time stamp (but I can't rule those out).

To be legal, do consider the license Apple included with your system has wordings for you to use that copy of the software on that one mac and that you can't transfer that license except by transferring the hardware (the license words things to tie the license to the hardware). You can then check with a local lawyer to determine how that license is going to be "legal" where you live.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find the "Install Mac OS X Lion"? It downloaded it automatically from the App Store and ran it immediately.

Comment: It deleted itself to save space. To download another copy - open the App Store - select any tab but **purchased** and hold the **option** key down when clicking on **purchased**.

Comment: Hmmm... It isn't in the list of purchased items. Using the option (alt) key doesn't help ether.

Comment: You might have to ask [billing support](https://expresslane.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.do?&PRKEYS=131629&category_id=SC0082&symptom_id=20258) if it's not shown in purchased under your account.